pygame.font.SysFont always loading 'FreeSans' regardless of font specified
When using pygame.font.SysFont to load a font, no matter what font I provide it always resolves to 'FreeSans'.

I tried running it in a new console (image provided) and same issue.
The code i used was pg.font.SysFont("Arial", 20) and when printing the fonts name it outputs 'FreeSans'.
It used to work when I was on windows. I'm on ubuntu now.

Bruh, I just realized Arial isn't a supported font on ubuntu, I just thought it was. Sorry.

Supported: yes, maybe not installed on your machine. See e.g. this question on askubunutu.
